# (HY000/1712): Index term_relationships is corrupted in /wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1868

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

Recently the Wordpress Database of my website was corrupted. There wasn't any backup of my database so I couldn't rectify the issue.

Seems the Table gj_term_relationships got corrupted due to which Menu, Related posts, Category, Tags aren't working.

Whenever I add a menu, related posts widget, it shows the following error:

> Warning:  mysqli_query(): (HY000/1712): Index gj_term_relationships is
>   corrupted in /home/nschopra22g/examweb.in/wp-includes/wp-db.php on
>   line 1868

The error is always present on my website www.examweb.in that can be checked through the page source if hidden.

I am having an average knowledge about Wordpress but nothing much about database stuff. I tried emptying the following tables:

```
gj_term_relationships

gj-term_meta

gj_term_taxonomy

gj_terms
```

The error is still there. Please help me out to sort out this issue. I'm unable to add Menu to my wordpress site due to this.

Comment: Is your posts,categories,pages are going to be view-able?

Comment: Hey Pranav,
Posts  & pages are accessible without any issue but if I add category or tag to any post and open the tag, it doesn't show any post attached with it. 

Also the Wordpress Menu functionality isn't working. Whenever I add a any item to menu, and save it, all my changes are gone. The menu items ain't being saved.